# Find Xml tags based on specific inner tag

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++

I have an xml file which contains  tags. I want to delete all `<value>` tags from the file which contains an inner `<isActive>` tag. I am trying this with regex find and replace in Notepad++.

I created this regex and i am not able to proceed further.

```
<value>.*?</value>
```

Below is the sample xml file`

```
<value>
                <fullName>CMT - AAPAC - ANZ - Telstra - Media</fullName>
                <default>false</default>
                <label>CMT - AAPAC - ANZ - Telstra - Media</label>
            </value>
            <value>
                <fullName>CMT - AAPAC - ASEAN - C&amp;M - Comms</fullName>
                <default>false</default>
                <isActive>false</isActive>
                <label>CMT - AAPAC - ASEAN - C&amp;M - Comms</label>
            </value>
```

The output of the file after removing should look like below

```
<value>
                <fullName>CMT - AAPAC - ANZ - Telstra - Media</fullName>
                <default>false</default>
                <label>CMT - AAPAC - ANZ - Telstra - Media</label>
            </value>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

**FindWhat**: `(?s)<value>(?:(?!<value>).)*?<isActive>.*?</value>`
**Replace With**: (empty string)

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/JeSPUS/1). Details:

- `(?s)` - *`.` matches newline* mode on
- `<value>` - a string
- `(?:(?!<value>).)*?` - any char, zero or more occurrences, but as few as possible, that does not start `value` substring
- `<isActive>` - a string
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `</value>` - a string.

See demo and settings:

[image]